# Translating model attributes does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I need to translate the attributes of my model Category, I found this [documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#error-message-scopes)

I tried this

```
es:
  activerecord:
    models:
      category: Categoria
    attributes:
      category:
        name: Nombre
    errors:
      messages:
        blank: no puede estar en blanco
```

My model:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, :presence => true
end
```

but the translation of the attributes does not work:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7EO5.png)

Comment: In the rails console try issuing `Category.human_attribute_name :name` if it outputs 'Nombre' then the problem is in your error displaying method

Comment: @R.Sierra You are right, in my controller I had `@category.errors`, I changed it to `@category.errors.full_messages` and it returned the messages I wanted

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `locale` to `:es`.

To manage `locale`, check out this link: [Setup the Rails Application for Internationalization](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setup-the-rails-application-for-internationalization)

You also need to **restart** the `rails server` after adding `es.yml`

Comment: I have the file `es.yml`